# Comments view limited to 20 results - any way to increase to 50 or 100?

Tags: comments, spam, limit

Each day I manually delete the spam posted on my blog. The comments view allows a maximum of 20 comments in the view. When I have 200 spam entries - I need to click through 10 times to get rid of it all.

Is there a way I can view 50 or 100 comments in the wordpress admin window at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the amount of visible comments in the **Screen Options**:

[image]